# Escape XML entities only once

Tags: java, xml, apache, html-entities

I have the following XML snippet in a string **(note the double encoded &)**:

```
...
&lt;PARA&gt;
S&amp;amp;P
&lt;/PARA&gt;
...
```

My desired output would be:

```
> ... <PARA> S&amp;P </PARA> ...
```

If I use:

StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml()

The actual oputput is:

```
 > ... <PARA> S&P </PARA> ...
```

It seems that StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml() escapes the input twice, or as long as it contains entities.

Is there a better utility method, or simple solution that can unescape every xml entity (not just a few but all accentuated character) once, so that my encoded & part does not get screwed up?

Thank,
Peter

Comment: I am sure you have already checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833956/how-to-unescape-xml-in-java) but I put it here just in case. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use third-party libraries, you should include the library name and the version.

`StringEscapeUtils` is part of Apache Commons Text and Apache Commons Lang (deprecated). The latest versions (as of November 2017) are Commons Text 1.1 and Commons Lang 3.3.7. Both versions show correct results.

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;
public class EscapeTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s = "&lt;PARA&gt; S&amp;amp;P &lt;/PARA&gt;";
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(s));
  }
}
```

Output: `<PARA> S&amp;P </PARA>`

Comment: Thanks. The reason was that this text was part of XML text node. When a document was built it automatically unescaped the entity references. this is a little strange to me but I was just inspecting this when you wrote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a long winded way of doing it, but I can't use `Apache Commons`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "&lt;PARA&gt; S&amp;amp;P &lt;/PARA&gt;";
        String ea = unescapeXML(a);
        System.out.println(ea);
    }

    public static String unescapeXML(final String xml) {
        Pattern xmlEntityRegex = Pattern.compile("&(#?)([^;]+);");
        StringBuffer unescapedOutput = new StringBuffer(xml.length());

        Matcher m = xmlEntityRegex.matcher(xml);
        Map<String, String> builtinEntities = null;
        String entity;
        String hashmark;
        String ent;
        int code;
        while (m.find()) {
            ent = m.group(2);
            hashmark = m.group(1);
            if ((hashmark != null) && (hashmark.length() > 0)) {
                code = Integer.parseInt(ent);
                entity = Character.toString((char) code);
            } else {
                if (builtinEntities == null) {
                    builtinEntities = buildBuiltinXMLEntityMap();
                }
                entity = builtinEntities.get(ent);
                if (entity == null) {
                    entity = "&" + ent + ';';
                }
            }
            m.appendReplacement(unescapedOutput, entity);
        }
        m.appendTail(unescapedOutput);
        return unescapedOutput.toString();

    }

    private static Map<String, String> buildBuiltinXMLEntityMap() {
        Map<String, String> entities = new HashMap<>(10);
        entities.put("lt", "<");
        entities.put("gt", ">");
        entities.put("amp", "&");
        entities.put("apos", "'");
        entities.put("quot", "\"");
        return entities;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
<PARA> S&amp;P </PARA>
```