# how to change &apos; entity to ' in xml file

Tags: java, xml

In database I have a message template which contains `"it's"` in the string, so when I take that message template and make a xml format, I'm getting `it&apos;s` in xml tag.

```
sms.setMessage(createSMS.messageFormatter(sms).getMessage());

tagList = new TagList[4]; 
req.setTaglist(tagList);
tagList[0] = new TagList();
tagList[0].setTagName("OA");
tagList[0].setTagValue(dto.getDaInk());

tagList[1] = new TagList();
tagList[1].setTagName("DA");
sms.setMsisdnTosent(Utilities.appendCountryCode(sms.getMsisdnTosent()));
tagList[1].setTagValue(sms.getMsisdnTosent());    

tagList[2] = new TagList();
tagList[2].setTagName("MESSAGE");
tagList[2].setTagValue(sms.getMessage());

tagList[3] = new TagList();
tagList[3].setTagName(Tags.TONE_ID);
tagList[3].setTagValue(sms.getSongId());
```

I'm getting like this,

```
<tagData>
      <name>MESSAGE</name>
      <value>Dear customer it&quot;&quot;s a confirmation messege sent to activate  Tune ALLAHUMMA EGHFER LE ABAENA WA OMMAHATENA you just heard Latest,reply with *  to copy the Tune, of artist AL SHEIKH MAHER BIN HAMAD AL MUAIQLY and toneId is 176577,cndtn aply.</value>
</tagData>
```

But I want, `it&quot;&quot;s` this to be replaced with `it's`

Comment: Can you please show the code that you use to edit xml from your taglist array?

Comment: did you read about `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to unescape XML in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833956/how-to-unescape-xml-in-java)

Comment: How come that an single apostrophe `'` becomes two double quotes `""`???

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by yash you can use org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils on your xml variable before you edit it:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(xml);
```